# Projection onto affine-hulls

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of points. 
Let $L(S):=\{\sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i v_i \mid k>0, v_i\in S, \lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i = 1\}$ be the affine-hull of $S$. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

How would you formally define the projection $P(x, S)$ of $x$ onto $L(S)$?

Since $L(S)$ is a translation of a vector linear space $W$, say $p+W$, then if $P_W$ is the projection matrix onto $W$, I would say that $p+P_W(x-p)$ is the projection onto the affine-hull... but is this correct and the standard way to go?
I'm not really satisfied by this definition because the relation between $L(S)$ and $x$ is shadowed by $p,W \!$...

Comment: If you're making an affine hull of a set you usually call the elements of the set points rather than vectors

Answer (score 1):

I would define the projection on a affine subspace of an euclidean space as the map which sends any point to the closest one in the affine subspace.

In your case the subspace is defined as the smallest affine subspace containing a given set of points $v_1,\dots, v_k$. Let $w_j = v_{j}-v_k$ for $j=1,\dots, k-1$. You should apply the [orthonormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process to the vectors $w_j$ to find an orthonormal base $e_1,\dots, e_n$ such that the space generated by $e_1,\dots,e_m$ is equal to the space generated by $w_1,\dots,w_k$ (of course $m\le k$). In such a base the linear part of the projection is represented in coordinates by $P(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1, \dots, x_m, 0, \dots ,0)$.

Comment: That works, but is of almost no practical use

Comment: I added a suggestion for the computation.

Comment: You should prove that the computation actually finds the point (prove it's unique btw) that satisfies the definition

Comment: @miniBill the change of coordinates is an isometry (since the base is orthonormal) so it is enough to prove that the map $(x_1,\dots,x_m,0,\dots,0)$ is the projection on $R^m\subset R^n$. And this last statement is trivial.

Comment: You should say that $m$ should be minimal, plus, you've only talked about the linear part of the projection. Plus you still need to prove that that algorithm satisfies the definition. And that the definition is sound

Comment: Hi Ema, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The projection of a point $x$ onto $L(S)$ is the intersection of $x + W^\bot$ with $L(S)$, where $W$ is the linear part of $L(S)$ and $W^\bot$ is it's orthogonal space, that is, the linear space of vector orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: miniBill, this works if $dim(W)=1$, i.e. $L(S)$ is a line, but are you sure that the intersection $x+W^{\perp}\cap L(S)$ contains just one point in general ? Consider the case of intersecting two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ...

Comment: If the intersection exists then its dimension is $0$ by Grassman, but to prove the existence... I need to think some more

Comment: Uhm, the intersection must exist because of the dimensions of the subspaces involved, and the fact that they're not parallel, although I can't think of a more precise definition right now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a computationally more efficient way to project points onto the affine subspace (flat) than what you describe ($p + P_{\textit{null}(W)}( x - p )$).

Given ${W}$ with orthonormal columns, $P_{\textit{null}(W)} = {W} {W}^\top$
and ${I} - P_{\textit{null}(W)}$ are projection matrices onto the nullspace and row-space, respectively. If ${W}$'s columns are linearly independent but not orthonormal, $P_{\textit{null}(W)} = {W} ({W}^\top {W})^{-1} {W}^\top$. If W's columns aren't even linearly independent, I believe you can use the pseudoinverse instead of the inverse.

A couple of other useful properties of projection matrices: Given a projection matrix ${P}$, ${P}^\top={P}={P}{P}$. The eigenvalues of ${P}$ are either 0 or 1. If your linear subspace is defined implicitly by a basis orthogonal to it, it is probably computationally more efficient to get the needed projection matrix via $I - P$.